# Using "this" keyword in a JavaScript prototype method?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am very new to javascript prototypes. So I am wondering If the following is legal and will always work :

```
function Obj(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Obj.prototype.getName() {
   return this.name;
}
```

and then :

```
var obj1 = new Obj("one");
var obj2 = new Obj("two");
alert(obj1.getName() + " " + obj2.getName());
```

Will I get "one two". I know this is a simple example, but will things like this always reference object instances or will this mean the prototype or an event. Thanks

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yes, it works. But basically what I want to know is what the this object binds to in the prototype method

Comment: Consider using valid syntax; then it's *easy to test*. In any case, `this` evaluates to the *current receiver*.

Comment: `this` is set according to how the method is called, and not according to how the method is written.  So for `obj.method()`, `this` will be set to `obj` inside of `method()`.  For `obj.method.call(x)`, `this` inside of `method()` will be set to `x`.  It is determined by how it's called.

Comment: What that also means is that if you pass it as a callback to e.g. `onclick`, `this` will be set to the global `window` object rather than what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Setup Obj    
function Obj() {}
Obj.prototype.me = function () {return this;}

// Make some vars
var a = new Obj(), b = new Obj();

// find out what "this" is equal to
a.me() === a; // true
a.me() === b; // false
b.me() === a; // false
b.me() === b; // true
```

Comment: (Except for the initial misuse of "this" as an identifier, I think it succinctly demonstrates the operation of `this` in a prototype-method.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var Obj = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

bj.prototype.getName = function( ) {
    return this.name; // this refers to Obj
}

var obj1 = new Obj('Jeff');
var obj2 = new Obj('Joe');

console.log(obj1.getName()); // Jeff
console.log(obj2.getName());​ // Joe
```

I can't get that to work, but this works fine. this should refer to the object you are calling the method on.

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzZ7x/)

Comment: Yes, the post had a syntax error in it. However, consider expanding on what `obj1.getName()` (and `obj2.getName()`) evaluate to and why: don't provide an answer that *requires* running code to see the expected results :)